# Route plotter python

Tags: python

So python 3 returns me an error but I do not know the cause.
This is the exercise I have to do for homework.

In a certain region all places are the one by road. But one-way traffic for all roads; if you are allowed to go from A to B via the direct route, you can not along that road from B to A. If you want to, you will have to take a detour.

Above is an example of an area with five places and a road between each pair you can only go one way. The roads CA and DB seem to intersect, but it is there not possible to switch away; for example, they run under and over a viaduct.

In such an area you search for a route where you visit each place exactly once. In this example is such a route ADBCE or DCAEB or DBCAE. Note: You will not be asked to go back again to go to the place where you started.

Write a program that first reads a number N from standard input (2 is less than N is less than 27).

This indicates the number of places in the area, the places are named as one capital letter; the first N capital letters are used as place name.

Then your program of standard input in N lines reads information about the direction of the connecting roads. On the first line, the N links from A to all other places; a 0 means that the road ends in A, a 1 that starts the road in A. The following rules are about the next places. There is always exactly one way between two places; there are no roads of a place to himself!

Your program writes to standard output one line with a route in which all places are visited exactly once. There is always a solution possible. There may be multiple good solutions.

Example:

```
Input: 
       5

       01011

       00100

       10001

       01101

       01000

Output:
       ADBCE
```

This is what it looks like with N = 5:

[verbindingen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDJNk.png)

This is my code:

```
import sys

#N = int(sys.stdin.readline()) #5

#verbindingen = []

N = 5

verbindingen = [['0', '1', '0', '1', '1'],
                ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
                ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1'],
                ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1'],
                ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0']]

#for i in range(0, N):
#    y = [str(a) for a in str(int(sys.stdin.readline()))]
#    verbindingen.append(y)
#    while len(verbindingen[i]) < N:
#        verbindingen[i].insert(0, '0')

k = 0
l = 0

letter = []
v = 0

while v < 5:
    for pad in range(0, N):
        if verbindingen[k][l] == 1:
            letter.append(verbindingen[k])
            k = verbindingen.index(verbindingen[k][l])
            break
        else:
            if l < 5:
                l = l + 1
            else:
                l = 0
    v = v + 1

print(letter)
```

I get an indexerror: list out of range

How do I solve this error? Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
The error is resolved but now I do not know why my code does not do what I want it to do. Does someone else know how to solve this exercise? I really hit a dead end now and I do not know how to solve this one.

Comment: You test `l < 5` before increasing the value of l, which is nice. However, if `l=4` you will add `1` and get `l` equal to `5`. However, indexes in verbingen goes from `0` to `4` in both dimensions. It should then be `l < 4`.

However, your code will return an empty list ! I guess you are still missing some point of your exercice :)

Comment: @Liris thank you for your answer! But I don't know what I'm missing. I want to append the array letter with the index numbers but why doesn't it do that? Is there another way to solve this. I hit a dead end...

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to use recursion. I read that somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually multiple problems in your code.

A very good way to test codes and find bad behaviors is to print things at some steps. For example, you could print something each time you verify the condition
`verbindingen[k][l] == 1`, which would meake you realize that this condition is never verified :)

Indeed, the lists inside verbindingen contains `strings`, while `1` is an integer. Then, the condition 1 == `1` will always return false. You need to choose between working only with integers, or only with strings. You can go from one type to another by using the functions `int()` and `str()`.

Finally, the line 
            k = verbindingen.index(verbindingen[k][l]))
will not work, as `verbindingen` is a list of **lists**, while `verbindingen[k][l]` is supposed to be an integer or a string(see first remark). I guess it should be:

```
    k = verbindingen[k].index(verbindingen[k][l])
```

If `verbindingen` has to stay an array of strings, one example could then be:

```
import sys

#N = int(sys.stdin.readline()) #5

#verbindingen = []

N = 5

verbindingen = [['0', '1', '0', '1', '1'],
                ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
                ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1'],
                ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1'],
                ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0']]

#for i in range(0, N):
#    y = [str(a) for a in str(int(sys.stdin.readline()))]
#    verbindingen.append(y)
#    while len(verbindingen[i]) < N:
#        verbindingen[i].insert(0, '0')

k = 0
l = 0

letter = []
v = 0

while v < 5:
    for pad in range(0, N):
        if verbindingen[k][l] == str(1): ##### Look at the use of the str() function
            print('Matched found') #### this in the line I used to find the mistake in your code
            letter.append(verbindingen[k])
            k = verbindingen[k].index(verbindingen[k][l]) ##### See here the last change
            break
        else:
            if l < 4:
                l = l + 1
            else:
                l = 0
    v = v + 1

print(letter)
```

However, I would recommend you to always work with integers if this is the only thing that there will be in your strings.